# NDSolve solution for driven damped pendulum diverges

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve numerically for the system of the driven damped pendulum using Mathematica. This is the second-order nonlinear equation
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x} + 2 \beta \dot{x}+ \omega_0^2  \sin
    x = \gamma  \omega_0^2 \cos[\omega t]
\end{equation}
The Mathematica code I used is simply

```
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 β x'[t] + ω0^2  Sin[x[t]] == γ  ω0^2 Cos[ω t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 500}, PrecisionGoal -> 20][[1]];
```

With parameters

```
β = ω0/4; γ = 0.2; ω = 2 π; ω0 =  1.5 ω;
```

However, the solution

```
x[t] /. s
```

Is an interpolation function defined only for $t\in [0,101]$ roughly. Plotting the function shows that it suddenly diverges at $t \approx 101$, which clearly should not happen. 
I tried changing the PrecisionGoal but this only change the exact value at which the function diverges - it still diverges at some value well before $t=500$. The problem persists for other values of the parameters, when I change $\gamma$.

Is there any way to get an accurate solution for longer times?

Comment: You should get a very helpful warning about `MaxSteps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using exact values (e.g. setting `γ = 1/5` instead of `γ = 0.2`) and increasing the `MaxSteps` option should yield a reasonable result. Below, I add the filigree of also using a method I tend to prefer for problems with oscillatory solutions (although I've found that just setting `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` without increasing `MaxSteps` still works well):

```
xp = With[{γ = 1/5, ω = 2 π},
     Block[{ω0 = 3 ω/2, β}, β = ω0/4;
           x /. First @ 
           NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 β x'[t] + ω0^2 Sin[x[t]] == γ ω0^2 Cos[ω t], 
                    x[0] == x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 500}, MaxSteps -> 1*^5, 
                   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", PrecisionGoal -> 20]]]
```

Inspect a few sections:

```
{{Plot[xp[t], {t, 0, 50}], Plot[xp[t], {t, 100, 150}]},
 {Plot[xp[t], {t, 350, 400}], Plot[xp[t], {t, 450, 500}]}} // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: driven damped pendulum solution]

Comment: Thanks! I now want to create a list of solutions for different values of $\gamma$. Simply defining a table with the command above and $g$ replacing 1/5, running from, say, 1.06 to 1.08 in steps of 0.001 doesn't work. Is there any way I can create a list of solutions for different $\gamma$?

Comment: @Peter, that's what `ParametricNDSolve` is for.

Comment: Ok, looks like it is time to update to Mathematica 9 :).

Comment: @Peter, oh yes :-) many good new `NDSolve` features...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `NDSolve` but plotting:

```
β=ω0/4;γ=1/5;ω=2 π;ω0=3/2 ω;
 tend = 500;
s = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + 
     2 β x'[t] + ω0^2 Sin[
       x[t]] == γ ω0^2 Cos[ω t], x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, tend}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Plotting a smaller subrange helps:

```
Plot[s[t], {t, 300, 400}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]